# Faster way than using $in for MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

At peak times the MongoDB for my site is being very slow in responding and I'm trying to figure out why this is. One query that I think may be the culprit is something like this (from a Meteor app):

`Players.find({_id: {$in: playerIds}});`

Where `playerIds` is an array of 15 unique strings. There are 600 or so players in the `Players` collection and there is an index on the `_id` field.

Is there a faster way to perform this query? Is there a way to restructure the database to make it faster? Does this even look like a problematic query, or is the problem most likely elsewhere?

Comment: can u share the explain output from the mongodb to understand this better ?

Comment: A tool such as Kadira could provide some insight and you won't need to speculate. Why not use something like this?

Comment: $in on _id with just 15 inputs should be blazingly fast. Check your mongo logfile for long-running queries first, and confirm that this query actually is the culprit.

Comment: I use kadira but it shows a lot of database operations taking 30 seconds plus.

Comment: Do any of them consist of the one you mentioned in the question? There are articles by the Kadira team regarding DB optimization, but this particular query is unlikely to be the culprit. You may want to be more selective regarding the amount of "reactivity" you use. Anyway, hard to tell without some more concrete measurements.

Comment: Ok. So I'll keep searching. How would disabling reactivity help things with the db speed? Does meteor just read from the oplog which mongo would producing either way to sync with the replica set?

Comment: This is how I ended up solving the problems: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongo-scaling-issues/27905/24?u=elie

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query mentioned in the question is fast and nothing has to be done about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something along these lines too, and I found a few things that really help with this (I hope it helps).

**mup/mupx:** If you are using mup/mupx for something like EC2, the older version of Mongodb is really slow particularly (it seems) when in docker. What I suggest you do is install Mongodb 3.2 on the server and then insert the Mongodb address into your mup config under env

such as MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://your-server-address/your-app', Also I found using a local address was way quicker than using a global address (good practice if you want to shard).

**Funny Futures:** I had a pretty huge memory leak when unresolved http calls kept waiting for a future. This in turn made the mongodb client take nearly 90s to perform a simple task. So it may not actually be mongodb, check all your code and make sure that methods don't take too long.